# Set sort-order field based on alphabetically ordering of another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've recently added a couple of fields to some tables in my database (SQL Server 2005) to allow users to customize the sort order of the rows. I've followed this pattern for all of the tables:

```
-- Alter the InvoiceStatus table
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceStatus] ADD [Disabled] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceStatus] ADD [SortOrder] int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
GO
-- Use the primary key as the default sort order
UPDATE [dbo].[InvoiceStatus]
   SET [SortOrder] = [InvoiceStatusId]
GO
```

Normally, as you can see, I've used the primary key as the default sort order. Now I am however in the situation that I would like to use the alphabetical ordering of a text field in the table as the default sort order.

Using the above table as an example (which has a text field `[InvoiceStatusName]`), is there a similar nice and short query I could write to use the alphabetical ordering of `[InvoiceStatusName]` as the default sort order?

***Update:***
The question is already answered, but some has pointed out that this solution might not be ideal so I just want to add some context for future references. This is an old system (not legacy-old, but it has been around for quite some years) in use a handful of different places.

There are several lists/drop-downs in the application with your typical "status" type (such as *invoice status*, *order status*, *customer type* etc.). Back when the system was first written these were standard values in use every place (not meant to be changed in any way), but some users have started to request the ability to add new statuses, remove those no longer in use and specify a custom sort order (one status might be more frequently used, and it is thus nice to have it at the top of the list).

The easiest way I found to do this (without having to mess around with too much of the old code) was to add two new fields, `Disabled` and `SortOrder`, to all the relevant tables. The `Disabled` field is used to "hide" un-used types (cannot delete them because of referential integrity, and the value they hold does also need to be kept), and the `SortOrder` field is there so the users can specify their own custom sort order. Since all the relevant tables also share these same two columns, it was very easy to make a simple interface to handle the sorting (and disabling) in a generic way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
;WITH so AS
(
SELECT 
   SortOrder,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY InvoiceStatusName) AS rn
FROM   dbo.InvoiceStatus
)
UPDATE so SET SortOrder = rn
```

Comment: +1 thx Martin. I've learned something new today. *btw, you can drop the InvoiceStatusID column.*

Comment: Thanks to both Martin and Lieven. Both your suggestions are good, but I chose Martin's as the accepted because it had the cleanest look.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms186734.aspx&ei=-nv3TL7vIcuyhAez-5XHDw&usg=AFQjCNEHsNWb4rsjrI0__ylxO3AXi1iwww&sig2=WZooeLbgHY8mq84USOK7Iw) function to map the sorted name to an integer.

```
UPDATE  dbo.InvoiceStatus
SET     SortOrder = ivsn.Number
FROM    dbo.InvoiceStatus ivs
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT dbo.InvoiceStatusID
                 , [number] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY InvoiceStatusName)
          FROM   dbo.InvoiceStatus
        ) ivsn ON ivsn.InvoiceStatusID = ivs.InvoiceStatusID
```

You should ask yourself though if this scheme is the best solution for your problem. The implementation as is doesn't scale well.

Comment: You don't need a self join for this.

Comment: @Martin: I was pondering on that but couldn't figure out how to write it *without* the self join. If you create a new answer without the self join, I would upvote it.

Comment: @Lieven - Done! You can update the table expression itself. (works with either CTE or derived table)

Comment: @Martin - now I've seen the CTE, how would it work with a derived table?

Comment: `UPDATE so SET SortOrder = rn FROM (SELECT SortOrder, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY InvoiceStatusName) AS rn FROM   InvoiceStatus) so`

Comment: <duh> didn't know it was that easy </duh>. Thx again. *Maybe you should write another answer so I can upvote you again.*

Answer (score 1):

The way you have chosen to implement table sorting is unusual and apparently restricted to sorting by integers only.

Really I'd recommend you redesign your sorting sub-system in another way.

e.g Have a meta-data table somewhere that holds the name of the column that users want to sort by, and then use `ORDER BY (columnname)` on the relevant queries

edit: Oh wait, we're talking about lookup tables and letting users change the order. Now I've got my head around that your implementation makes a lot more sense to me.

Comment: Nice update queries though, Martin and Lieven. I am the grumpy one at this party, evidently.

Comment: It didn't sounded grumpy to me and for what it's worth, I also think OP will want to change his design to accommodate future requests.

Comment: My intention is not to allow the users to choose which column the table should be ordered by. They should be able to control the actual sort order of the rows (used for presentation in the application).

Comment: Right. I can see that the [SortColumn] makes sense in that case. It still seems a little awkward to copy an entire default sequence into it though. What happens if the contents of the text column change?

Comment: @codeulike: some columns are blocked from editing the text (because they have special contextual meaning), but other than that nothing special happens if the user changes the content of a text column. The only reason why I "copy" an entire default sequence, is that when I patch the users' database to the next version, it should have an initial sensible order (compared to what they have today (which is alphabetically for a few tables, but mostly the same as the primary key for the others).

Comment: Thanks for editing your question, it makes a bit more sense to me now - we are talking about lookup tables and letting people choose the order of the items. Come to think of it, I've used a very similar system to your [Disabled] and [SortOrder] columns myself in the past : )